# Does fp-ts offer sequence for object?

Tags: functional-programming, fp-ts

`R.sequence` is endlessly useful.  If I have this:

```
const p0 = {
  a: O.some(1),
  b: O.some(2),
};
```

I can do this:

```
const p0o = R.sequence(O.Applicative)(p);
```

and get back an `O.Option<Record<string, number>>`

What I cannot do is

```
const p1 = {
  a: O.some(1),
  b: O.some("2"),
};
const p1o = R.sequence(O.Applicative)(p);
```

Because p1o is not a "Record", it’s a more generalized object, so I get a compiler error.  I can rewrite it like this:

```
type RecordOf<F extends keyof URItoKind<any>, A> = {
  [K in keyof A]: Kind<F, A[K]>;
};

function sequenceObj<F extends URIS>(
  F: Applicative1<F>
): <K extends object>(ta: RecordOf<F, K>) => Kind<F, K> {
    return (obj) =>  R.sequence(F)(obj) as any;
}

const p1 = {
  a: O.some(1),
  b: O.some("2"),
};
const p1o = sequenceObj(O.Applicative)(p);
```

That works, and if I ate my Wheaties, I could probably get rid of the `as any` and update it to work all other Kinds of monads.

But I get the feeling the work would be pleonastic: there is probably some existing fp-ts idiom for doing exactly this, if only I knew its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer — don’t tell anybody, but I asked Chat-GPT — and yes, it is an idiom and the word I was missing was `Apply`, which, given how many times I had to write the word `Applicative`, makes me feel rather foolish.

```
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/lib/function';
import * as O from 'fp-ts/lib/Option';
import * as Apply from 'fp-ts/lib/Apply';

const p2 = pipe(
  {
    a: O.some(1),
    b: O.some('b'),
  },
  Apply.sequenceS(O.Applicative)
);
```

The `S` at the end of `sequenceS` stands for “Struct”.  There is also `sequenceT` for tuples.